# Globe icon on Mac menu bar, what is this?

Tags: macos, macos-monterey

I have an iMac with macOS Monterey.

What is this globe with a blue down arrow? This often shows up on my status bar and when I click on it, nothing happens!

[image]

<sup>Image zoomed, for those of us not carrying microscopes… ;)</sup>

[image]

Comment: Try to hover over it. On Windows, a right-click would have given more information, but perhaps the Mac has some equivalent.

Comment: Do you have LibreOffice installed? The only thing I've been able to find is saying it's related to automatic update searches for LibreOffice. The icon is notifying you there is a new update available to download and install. [bug report](https://www.mail-archive.com/libreoffice-bugs@lists.freedesktop.org/msg861338.html)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As mentioned by DrZoo in the comments, it's a LibreOffice icon that indicates an application update is available. See also [this question](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/406276/what-is-this-globe-icon-with-blue-down-arrow-in-my-menu-bar).